# JFileChooser close launches new window

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFileChooser that is launched by a button click which calls the ExportFileChooser.createAndShowGUI() method. It works fine accept for when I close the JFileChooser a new empty window titled ExportFileChooser opens, how can I correct this so it does not launch?

Here is the code:

```
package org.annotationRoi3D.io;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * This creates a dialog window for exporting 
 * and importing XML files.
 */
public class ExportFileChooser extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static File ExportFile;
    JFileChooser fcExport;

    public ExportFileChooser() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        fcExport = new JFileChooser();

        int returnValExport = fcExport.showSaveDialog(ExportFileChooser.this);
        if (returnValExport == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            ExportFile = fcExport.getSelectedFile();
            org.annotationRoi3D.io.ExportXML.OutputXML();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frameExport = new JFrame("FileChooserExport");
        frameExport.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add content to the window.
        frameExport.add(new ExportFileChooser());

        //Display the window.
        frameExport.pack();
        frameExport.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Well, that's what your code does: it creates a JFrame with `FileChooseExport` as title, and makes it visible. Why does the code do that if you don't want to show a frame?

Comment: @JBNizet Please make that an answer

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's what your code does: it creates a JFrame with `"FileChooseExport"` as title, and makes it visible. Why does the code do that if you don't want to show a frame?

The code of the ActionListener of your button should simply be:

```
JFileChooser fcExport = new JFileChooser();

int returnValExport = fcExport.showSaveDialog(thePanelContainingTheButton);
if (returnValExport == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    ...
}
```

You don't need another ExportFileChooser panel, placed in another JFrame made visible, just to open a JFileChooser. The javadoc of JFileChoose contains example usage, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback, I have found the solution.

Upon button click I do not call CreateAndShowGUI() but now create a new instance of ExportFileCHooser like this:

ExportFileChooser exportWindow = new ExportFileChooser();

that seems to work perfectly